# Problema com Google Maps V2 no android SDK

Tags: android, api, google-maps

Estou recebendo este erro no meu projeto Android que utiliza a API V2 do google maps:

```
    02-24 11:18:03.627: D/memalloc(24852): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x53e95000 size:2949120 offset:2334720 fd:51
02-24 11:18:04.527: E/Random(24852): > 17.386018618908807, 78.48646956337022
02-24 11:18:04.557: E/Random(24852): > 17.38412543640696, 78.48624683166463
02-24 11:18:04.587: E/Random(24852): > 17.38586197038353, 78.4868721802265
02-24 11:18:04.607: E/Random(24852): > 17.38442155970874, 78.48580890457683
02-24 11:18:04.627: E/Random(24852): > 17.384699149953665, 78.4870218788892
02-24 11:18:04.647: E/Random(24852): > 17.385163909742342, 78.48621221061424
02-24 11:18:04.667: E/Random(24852): > 17.385114499391356, 78.4873707292564
02-24 11:18:04.687: E/Random(24852): > 17.385180855826714, 78.48744879889605
02-24 11:18:04.717: E/Random(24852): > 17.385454853045843, 78.48692191930289
02-24 11:18:04.737: E/Random(24852): > 17.385926863638797, 78.48699800017822
02-24 11:18:04.757: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(24852): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
02-24 11:18:04.867: D/memalloc(24852): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x53b95000 size:1187840 offset:573440 fd:96
02-24 11:18:04.967: D/memalloc(24852): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5474f000 size:1720320 offset:1187840 fd:102
02-24 11:18:04.987: D/memalloc(24852): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x548f3000 size:6021120 offset:5406720 fd:105
02-24 11:18:05.167: D/memalloc(24852): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x54eb1000 size:6635520 offset:6021120 fd:108
02-24 11:18:05.167: D/memalloc(24852): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5429f000 size:4915200 offset:4300800
02-24 11:18:05.167: D/memalloc(24852): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51a02000 size:2334720 offset:1720320
02-24 11:18:05.167: D/memalloc(24852): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x53e95000 size:2949120 offset:2334720
02-24 11:18:05.517: D/memalloc(24852): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x54265000 size:4833280 offset:4300800 fd:45
02-24 11:18:05.527: D/memalloc(24852): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x53e95000 size:2252800 offset:1720320 fd:48
02-24 11:18:11.727: E/Google Maps Android API(24852): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
02-24 11:18:47.077: D/memalloc(24852): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5474f000 size:1720320 offset:1187840
02-24 11:18:47.077: D/memalloc(24852): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x54265000 size:4833280 offset:4300800
02-24 11:18:47.077: D/memalloc(24852): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x53e95000 size:2252800 offset:1720320
```

Já inclui a lib `google_play_serv` no meu projeto.
Também estou executando o projeto num device real.
Estou usando como base: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor coloque mais informações sobre o contexto, código e/ou o stacktrace completo.

Comment: Acho que vou incluiu errado a lib do google play da uma verificada ai. Verifica também se a chave gerada ta correta (nome do pacote ao final do SHA). Com as informações que você deu mais o erro acho que pode ser uma dessas duas coisas.

Comment: Inclui esta lib : sdk\extras\google\google_play_services  agora ele diz não tenho autorização  E/Google Maps Android API(4384): Authorization failure. pelo que vi tem duas chaves uma para debug é uma para produção acho que ai o meu problema

Comment: Exato. Refaz o passo de gerar o SHA e pegar a Key no google. Se ta testando o APP em debug ainda, usa da debug.key. Vai em Window -> Pereferens -> Android -> Build. Nessa janela vai ter o SHA da sua chave, com essa sequencia de caracteres é que você vai gerar a Key no google.

Comment: Depois de tentar de tudo resolvi refazer o manifest, não sei exatamente em que parte estava o erro, mas resolveu. De qualquer maneira obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe duas coisas no seu logcat que podem indicar o seu problema.

***02-24 11:18:11.727: E/Google Maps Android API(24852): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).***

Provavelmente você não configurou a chave de acesso a API ou informou errado, acessar o [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect) verificar as chaves.

verificar tambem se você configurou as tag obrigatórios no seu *AndroidManifest.xml* no elemento [application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="digite sua API_KEY"/>
```

Obs: Correu alguns casos que tive que esperar alguns minutos para que as chaves possa utilizadas.

***02-24 11:18:04.757: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(24852): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.***

Isso quer dizer que você não fez a referencia ao projeto de Resources do google maps, como por exemplo imagens, layouts etc.
Para resolver esse problema você tem que baixar e referenciar o Projeto Google Play Service junto com seu projeto, para tal procedimento você tem que acessar o [tutorial de configuração do google play service](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html?hl=pt-br)

Fonte e tutorial completo em [Documentação API Android do Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Comment: O meu problemas estava no manifest depois de refazer ele, funcionou corretamente! Obrigado.